# jQuery .show() - show / hide for multiple elements

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I am trying to achieve this:

1. Create a page with multiple lists, each containing a nested list to be revealed when a link is clicked.
2. When a link is clicked, and the content is revealed, when clicking on another link, the previously revealed content is hidden, and the new one revealed.
3. When clicking anywhere on the page away from the revealed content, this click will hide the item.

Here is a Pen showing the reveal action working as expected, but this does not function as I'd like so far.

http://codepen.io/juxprose/pen/pzvuC

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.trigger').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.show').hide();    
    $(this).next('.show').slideDown();
});

$(document).click(function () {
    $('.show').slideUp();    
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bauqa/)

Comment: That good - thanks! The only issue here is that it closes the opened content when clicking on that content itself. There may well be links within that content, so clicking on the content itself shouldn't hide it. Many thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This code should do what you want if I understood well :

html :

```
<ul id="listItems">
    <li><a href="#">Item1</a>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1.1</li>
            <li>Item 1.2</li>
            <li>Item 1.3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item2</a>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 2.1</li>
            <li>Item 2.2</li>
            <li>Item 2.3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item3</a>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 3.1</li>
            <li>Item 3.2</li>
            <li>Item 3.3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#listItems ul").hide();
   $("#listItems a").on("click", function() {
       $("#listItems ul").hide();
       $(this).next().show();
   });
   $(document).click(function(e) {
    if ( $(e.target).closest('#listItems').length === 0 ) {
        $("#listItems ul").hide();
    }
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It's good, but when I use mulitple UL's on the page (as I plan to), the "click away" function doesn't work that well, I've made a new Pen for yours here: http://codepen.io/juxprose/pen/oHKkf

Comment: It is normal.. you are using the same id... the id is unique but you have several times the same one... instead of using an id, use a class and change the code to use .listsItems instead of #listItems

Comment: so it works... it is just that your ul are very long, so when you click outside you may click on a ul so it does not go away... You can put all of this in a div with an id #listsItems and choose a width for example or you can choose to calculate the closest to the <a>... you do as you wish and see what is working for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('.trigger').click(function(){
    $('.show').slideUp();
    $(this).next('.show').slideDown(); 
});
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/8jedA/

Comment: That's excellent thanks. Great, that's nearly perfect, the only thing I'd like it to do in addition to that functionality, is to hide the opened items when clicked away from the opened content, thanks!