# click outside div to hide, is hiding when clicked inside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a menu where when a div is clicked it opens another div with the contents. I wanted it close when the user clicked anywhere else. That part seems to work, however it also closes when the div itself is clicked.

The user should be able to click inside the div without it closing,

I was using answers from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811536/jquery-show-show-hide-for-multiple-elements) as a guide but they were using ordered lists instead of divs, is there an issue with e.target.class ?

Thanks for any help.

```js
$('.trigger').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.header-menu-container').hide();
    $(this).next('.header-menu-container').slideDown();
});

$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.class == 'header-menu-container' || e.target.class == 'header-menu-contents') 
        return;
    $('.header-menu-container').slideUp();
});
```

Please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/75JaR/3/

Comment: You have to create 2 divs one as a cover and the other one with the content and set on the cover the onclick to remove both divs or just make the visibility hidden

Comment: use toggle instead of click function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `class` to `className`...

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.className == 'header-menu-container' || e.target.className == 'header-menu-contents') return;
    $('.header-menu-container').slideUp();
});
```

**[updated jsfiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/75JaR/4/)**

Incidentally, if you add any further classes to the container and contents elements then the above code won't work.  The following code would be more suitable as it will work no matter how many extra classes you add...

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    var $this = $(e.target);
    if ($this.hasClass("header-menu-container")) return;
    if ($this.hasClass("header-menu-contents")) return;
    $('.header-menu-container').slideUp();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

stop the event bubbling up to the document when the div is clicked, then you don't have to do the class check.

http://jsfiddle.net/75JaR/7/

```
$('.trigger').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.header-menu-container').hide();
    $(this).next('.header-menu-container').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    }).slideDown();
});

$(document).click(function (e) {
    $('.header-menu-container').slideUp();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this instead:

```
if ( $(e.target).is('.header-menu-container') || $(e.target).is('.header-menu-contents') )
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a `click` event on the div to stop hiding it once clicked on it.

```
    $('.trigger').click(function (e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
    $('.header-menu-container').hide();
    $(this).next('.header-menu-container').slideDown();
    });

$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.class == 'header-menu-container' || e.target.class == 'header-menu-contents') return;
    $('.header-menu-container').slideUp();
    $('.header-menu-container').click(function(){

       return false;
    });
});
```